# Piping Apache log through script - not working for error log

Tags: shell, logging, apache2, lamp

I'm building a LAMP server for multiple users to practice web development using mod_userdir, and have written scripts to break out the access and error logs to log directories within the user's home directories.

The access_log.sh script is working fine (log lines get written both to the main server log file, and the user's log file), but error_log.sh is only updating the main log file. This is error_log.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS='
'

userlogfile=error.log
syslogfile=/var/log/apache2/cs-web_error.log

homedirs=`ls -d /home/*`

while read logline; do
    echo -e ${logline} >> ${syslogfile}
    #echo -e "writing ${logline} to ${syslogfile}" #TESTING

    for homedir in $homedirs; do
        userlogpath="${homedir}/logs/${userlogfile}"
        if echo $logline | grep ${homedir} > /dev/null; then
            echo -e ${logline} >> ${userlogpath}
            #echo -e "writing ${logline} to ${userlogpath}" #TESTING
        fi
    done
done
```

The logging config for Apache is:

```
CustomLog "| ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_log.sh" common
ErrorLog "| ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_log.sh"
```

If I uncomment the #TESTING statements, I get output like this when piping the error log through the script:

```
writing [Fri Sep 06 12:15:11 2013] [error] [client 193.61.230.178] PHP Parse error:
syntax error, unexpected 'select' (T_STRING) in /home/ginny/htdocs/test.php on line 12 
to /var/log/apache2/cs-web_error.log
writing [Fri Sep 06 12:15:11 2013] [error] [client 193.61.230.178] PHP Parse error:  
syntax error, unexpected 'select' (T_STRING) in /home/ginny/htdocs/test.php on line 12 
to /home/ginny/logs/error.log
```

... which shows that the grep statement is working. Also, running manually like this, the file is created and written to:

```
root@cs-web:~# ls -l /home/ginny/logs/
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2213 Sep  6 12:53 access.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9984 Sep  6 12:49 error.log
```

What I'm struggling to understand is why this works for the access log, and not for the error log - the only differences are:

```
root@cs-web:/var/log/apache2# diff access_log.sh error_log.sh
6,7c6,7
< userlogfile=access.log
< syslogfile=/var/log/apache2/cs-web_access.log
---
> userlogfile=error.log
> syslogfile=/var/log/apache2/cs-web_error.log
12a13
>     #echo -e "writing ${logline} to ${syslogfile}"
15,17c16,17
<         homedir=${homedir#/home/}
<         userlogpath="/home/${homedir}/logs/${userlogfile}"
<         if echo $logline | egrep "/(~|users/)${homedir}/" > /dev/null; then
---
>         userlogpath="${homedir}/logs/${userlogfile}"
>         if echo $logline | grep ${homedir} > /dev/null; then
18a19
>             #echo -e "writing ${logline} to ${userlogpath}"
```

Suggestions gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote your variables properly and use arrays instead. `readarray` is also better than depending on word splits and possible generation through pathname expansion.

```
#!/bin/bash

#IFS=$'\n'  ## No longer needed.

userlogfile=error.log
syslogfile=/var/log/apache2/cs-web_error.log

readarray -t homedirs < <(ls -d /home/*)

while read logline; do
    echo -e "${logline}" >> "${syslogfile}"
    #echo -e "writing ${logline} to ${syslogfile}" #TESTING

    for homedir in "${homedirs[@]}"; do
        userlogpath="${homedir}/logs/${userlogfile}"
        if echo "$logline" | grep "${homedir}" > /dev/null; then
            echo -e "${logline}" >> "${userlogpath}"
            #echo -e "writing ${logline} to ${userlogpath}" #TESTING
        fi
    done
done
```

But if your version is earlier than 4.0, then just use the other method:

```
IFS=$'\n'
homedirs=($(ls -d /home/*))
```

I suggest that you also use the same concept with the other script for safety.

**UPDATE**

In your second script you no longer tried to trim `$homedir` with `/home/` which means it's possible that if `"$homedir"` doesn't begin with `/home/`, `$userlogpath` would be `<user>/logs/${userlogfile}"`, whereas in your first script it would still be `/home/<user>/logs/${userlogfile}`. Try to use these lines in your `error_log.sh` as well.

```
     homedir=${homedir#/home/}
     userlogpath="/home/${homedir}/logs/${userlogfile}"
```

Comment: Oh me of little faith - sorry about the earlier doubt, konsolebox - I tried your changes, and it's working. Have to say I don't really understand why that solves the problem, but it does.

Than you.